# can't get past certification path issue on android for https connection

Tags: android, exception, https, path, certificate

I've been trying to do an https connection to my server using HttpsUrlConnection.  The code keeps
throwing this exception:

java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

The certificate on my load balancer was issued by Comodo.  I would expect the android system to
recognize Comodo with having to add my server's certificte to the android system?

openssl check of the server shows a "Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)".
i have read that this is not necessarily the issue.  This is caused by the fact that no CA names are
 sent by the server?  On test on  generates the same return code.  Other tests 
 of my server pass (Wormly.com).

In order to try and remove the configuration of my load balancer from the equation, I thought I 
 would try and read from https://google.com.  I see the same exeption thrown by my code.  Below is 
 the code I used to try and do a GET from https://google.com and below that is the result of the 
 openssl test run on google from a linux instance at AWS.  This feels like a problem with my code 
 rather than the server configuration, but I'm stuck.

Any ideas on what I can try next?

```
package com.example.kinn_nat5;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class ExecuteGoogle extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private OnTaskCompleted listener;
    //private static final String LOG_TAG = "kinn_nat5";

     public ExecuteGoogle(OnTaskCompleted listener){
            this.listener=listener;
        }

     public Activity activity;
     public void SetActivity(Activity act)
     {
         this.activity = act;
             // Now here you can get getApplication()
     }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {


        URL url;


        HttpsURLConnection connection = null;

        try {

            url = new URL("https://google.com");           
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.1; E270BSA Build/JRO03H) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166  Safari/535.19");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml,text/html");         
            connection.setRequestProperty("Encoding","gzip,deflate");

            connection.setUseCaches (false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(false);
            connection.connect();

            //Get Response  
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();
            return response.toString();

        } 
        catch (Exception e) {   

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } 
    }        

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result != null && result.length() > 0) {
            listener.onTaskCompleted(result);
        activity = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        activity =null;
    }

}
```

openssl s_client -debug -connect google.com:443

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0x8418770 [0x84187b8] (225 bytes => 225 (0xE1))
0000 - 16 03 01 00 dc 01 00 00-d8 03 02 54 2d 72 d1 4d   ...........T-r.M
0010 - 3b f1 3f 4d a6 ca 4e 9e-93 a5 b0 4c 85 83 8a 41   ;.?M..N....L...A
0020 - d0 77 94 8f 51 20 86 86-15 e7 92 00 00 66 c0 14   .w..Q .......f..
0030 - c0 0a c0 22 c0 21 00 39-00 38 00 88 00 87 c0 0f   ...".!.9.8......
0040 - c0 05 00 35 00 84 c0 12-c0 08 c0 1c c0 1b 00 16   ...5............
0050 - 00 13 c0 0d c0 03 00 0a-c0 13 c0 09 c0 1f c0 1e   ................
0060 - 00 33 00 32 00 9a 00 99-00 45 00 44 c0 0e c0 04   .3.2.....E.D....
0070 - 00 2f 00 96 00 41 c0 11-c0 07 c0 0c c0 02 00 05   ./...A..........
0080 - 00 04 00 15 00 12 00 09-00 14 00 11 00 08 00 06   ................
0090 - 00 03 00 ff 01 00 00 49-00 0b 00 04 03 00 01 02   .......I........
00a0 - 00 0a 00 34 00 32 00 0e-00 0d 00 19 00 0b 00 0c   ...4.2..........
00b0 - 00 18 00 09 00 0a 00 16-00 17 00 08 00 06 00 07   ................
00c0 - 00 14 00 15 00 04 00 05-00 12 00 13 00 01 00 02   ................
00d0 - 00 03 00 0f 00 10 00 11-00 23 00 00 00 0f 00 01   .........#......
00e0 - 01                                                .
read from 0x8418770 [0x841dd18] (7 bytes => 7 (0x7))
0000 - 16 03 02 00 3d 02                                 ....=.
0007 - <SPACES/NULS>
read from 0x8418770 [0x841dd22] (59 bytes => 59 (0x3B))
0000 - 00 39 03 02 54 2d 74 72-fc 56 3c 21 70 c8 e5 88   .9..T-tr.V<!p...
0010 - fb 12 98 db 57 7a 6c 42-b6 89 6a 04 87 90 84 13   ....WzlB..j.....
0020 - ab 0c 05 8d 00 c0 13 00-00 11 ff 01 00 01 00 00   ................
0030 - 0b 00 04 03 00 01 02 00-23                        ........#
003b - <SPACES/NULS>
read from 0x8418770 [0x841dd1b] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 16 03 02 0e f6                                    .....
read from 0x8418770 [0x841dd20] (3830 bytes => 1347 (0x543))
0000 - 0b 00 0e f2 00 0e ef 00-07 71 30 82 07 6d 30 82   .........q0..m0.
0010 - 06 55 a0 03 02 01 02 02-08 7a 5b 0b d8 95 63 2f   .U.......z[...c/
0020 - 87 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48-86 f7 0d 01 01 05 05 00   .0...*.H........
0030 - 30 49 31 0b 30 09 06 03-55 04 06 13 02 55 53 31   0I1.0...U....US1
0040 - 13 30 11 06 03 55 04 0a-13 0a 47 6f 6f 67 6c 65   .0...U....Google
0050 - 20 49 6e 63 31 25 30 23-06 03 55 04 03 13 1c 47    Inc1%0#..U....G
0060 - 6f 6f 67 6c 65 20 49 6e-74 65 72 6e 65 74 20 41   oogle Internet A
0070 - 75 74 68 6f 72 69 74 79-20 47 32 30 1e 17 0d 31   uthority G20...1
0080 - 34 30 39 32 34 31 30 30-38 30 35 5a 17 0d 31 34   40924100805Z..14
0090 - 31 32 32 33 30 30 30 30-30 30 5a 30 66 31 0b 30   1223000000Z0f1.0
00a0 - 09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02-55 53 31 13 30 11 06 03   ...U....US1.0...
00b0 - 55 04 08 0c 0a 43 61 6c-69 66 6f 72 6e 69 61 31   U....California1
00c0 - 16 30 14 06 03 55 04 07-0c 0d 4d 6f 75 6e 74 61   .0...U....Mounta
00d0 - 69 6e 20 56 69 65 77 31-13 30 11 06 03 55 04 0a   in View1.0...U..
00e0 - 0c 0a 47 6f 6f 67 6c 65-20 49 6e 63 31 15 30 13   ..Google Inc1.0.
00f0 - 06 03 55 04 03 0c 0c 2a-2e 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65 2e   ..U....*.google.
0100 - 63 6f 6d 30 82 01 22 30-0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7   com0.."0...*.H..
0110 - 0d 01 01 01 05 00 03 82-01 0f 00 30 82 01 0a 02   ...........0....
0120 - 82 01 01 00 b7 a4 6a 8a-8f eb b5 a5 6e 3e 82 ef   ......j.....n>..
0130 - ac ab 49 29 37 47 95 c0-ee 1e a0 32 4d e8 b4 19   ..I)7G.....2M...
0140 - ce 4b 22 fb af 61 b9 21-8f 93 0c 44 c7 b9 c7 69   .K"..a.!...D...i
0150 - 54 ee f1 11 ab f5 8a 06-92 b1 56 7d ef c8 1c 23   T.........V}...#
0160 - b3 1a cf 80 f6 37 7b 9f-5e 93 6d df 6f 88 ad b2   .....7{.^.m.o...
0170 - 6e f5 0a 0a e0 ad 31 48-17 80 88 1c e0 33 d1 fd   n.....1H.....3..
0180 - 28 33 22 fe ca 17 b8 90-32 83 3f d8 20 1e a4 0e   (3".....2.?. ...
0190 - d1 9e c6 51 87 4c ba fe-2a 78 4a 7b 20 a1 09 83   ...Q.L..*xJ{ ...
01a0 - 8b 21 d3 13 6a c7 83 5b-0b 68 81 23 01 69 cb 70   .!..j..[.h.#.i.p
01b0 - e2 d2 62 e9 2c a0 dc 4c-1a 86 2e f4 8c 18 8a b2   ..b.,..L........
01c0 - 07 05 01 a9 d4 2f 57 80-31 7d dc 0a 5e 31 9d a9   ...../W.1}..^1..
01d0 - 67 87 54 1d 8a cd 66 ab-54 3b 11 4a 7a 07 3e c1   g.T...f.T;.Jz.>.
01e0 - 9a 04 b2 af 5d ba 7e a5-64 7f b2 38 9e 3b c4 e1   ....].~.d..8.;..
01f0 - 78 e4 e4 8e 4e b2 91 3d-3d 2f 90 1d 2a d7 3f ba   x...N..==/..*.?.
0200 - 27 c5 6c 42 7b 5a 89 29-fe bc 78 b9 e3 27 72 54   '.lB{Z.)..x..'rT
0210 - 2b ee c1 78 6a 5c d7 3f-77 28 18 5f 73 65 48 e6   +..xj\.?w(._seH.
0220 - 79 63 95 f3 02 03 01 00-01 a3 82 04 3a 30 82 04   yc..........:0..
0230 - 36 30 1d 06 03 55 1d 25-04 16 30 14 06 08 2b 06   60...U.%..0...+.
0240 - 01 05 05 07 03 01 06 08-2b 06 01 05 05 07 03 02   ........+.......
0250 - 30 82 03 10 06 03 55 1d-11 04 82 03 07 30 82 03   0.....U......0..
0260 - 03 82 0c 2a 2e 67 6f 6f-67 6c 65 2e 63 6f 6d 82   ...*.google.com.
0270 - 0d 2a 2e 61 6e 64 72 6f-69 64 2e 63 6f 6d 82 16   .*.android.com..
0280 - 2a 2e 61 70 70 65 6e 67-69 6e 65 2e 67 6f 6f 67   *.appengine.goog
0290 - 6c 65 2e 63 6f 6d 82 12-2a 2e 63 6c 6f 75 64 2e   le.com..*.cloud.
02a0 - 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65 2e 63-6f 6d 82 16 2a 2e 67 6f   google.com..*.go
02b0 - 6f 67 6c 65 2d 61 6e 61-6c 79 74 69 63 73 2e 63   ogle-analytics.c
02c0 - 6f 6d 82 0b 2a 2e 67 6f-6f 67 6c 65 2e 63 61 82   om..*.google.ca.
02d0 - 0b 2a 2e 67 6f 6f 67 6c-65 2e 63 6c 82 0e 2a 2e   .*.google.cl..*.
02e0 - 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65 2e 63-6f 2e 69 6e 82 0e 2a 2e   google.co.in..*.
02f0 - 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65 2e 63-6f 2e 6a 70 82 0e 2a 2e   google.co.jp..*.
0300 - 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65 2e 63-6f 2e 75 6b 82 0f 2a 2e   google.co.uk..*.
0310 - 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65 2e 63-6f 6d 2e 61 72 82 0f 2a   google.com.ar..*
0320 - 2e 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65 2e-63 6f 6d 2e 61 75 82 0f   .google.com.au..
0330 - 2a 2e 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65-2e 63 6f 6d 2e 62 72 82   *.google.com.br.
0340 - 0f 2a 2e 67 6f 6f 67 6c-65 2e 63 6f 6d 2e 63 6f   .*.google.com.co
0350 - 82 0f 2a 2e 67 6f 6f 67-6c 65 2e 63 6f 6d 2e 6d   ..*.google.com.m
0360 - 78 82 0f 2a 2e 67 6f 6f-67 6c 65 2e 63 6f 6d 2e   x..*.google.com.
0370 - 74 72 82 0f 2a 2e 67 6f-6f 67 6c 65 2e 63 6f 6d   tr..*.google.com
0380 - 2e 76 6e 82 0b 2a 2e 67-6f 6f 67 6c 65 2e 64 65   .vn..*.google.de
0390 - 82 0b 2a 2e 67 6f 6f 67-6c 65 2e 65 73 82 0b 2a   ..*.google.es..*
03a0 - 2e 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65 2e-66 72 82 0b 2a 2e 67 6f   .google.fr..*.go
03b0 - 6f 67 6c 65 2e 68 75 82-0b 2a 2e 67 6f 6f 67 6c   ogle.hu..*.googl
03c0 - 65 2e 69 74 82 0b 2a 2e-67 6f 6f 67 6c 65 2e 6e   e.it..*.google.n
03d0 - 6c 82 0b 2a 2e 67 6f 6f-67 6c 65 2e 70 6c 82 0b   l..*.google.pl..
03e0 - 2a 2e 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65-2e 70 74 82 12 2a 2e 67   *.google.pt..*.g
03f0 - 6f 6f 67 6c 65 61 64 61-70 69 73 2e 63 6f 6d 82   oogleadapis.com.
0400 - 0f 2a 2e 67 6f 6f 67 6c-65 61 70 69 73 2e 63 6e   .*.googleapis.cn
0410 - 82 14 2a 2e 67 6f 6f 67-6c 65 63 6f 6d 6d 65 72   ..*.googlecommer
0420 - 63 65 2e 63 6f 6d 82 11-2a 2e 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65   ce.com..*.google
0430 - 76 69 64 65 6f 2e 63 6f-6d 82 0c 2a 2e 67 73 74   video.com..*.gst
0440 - 61 74 69 63 2e 63 6e 82-0d 2a 2e 67 73 74 61 74   atic.cn..*.gstat
0450 - 69 63 2e 63 6f 6d 82 0a-2a 2e 67 76 74 31 2e 63   ic.com..*.gvt1.c
0460 - 6f 6d 82 0a 2a 2e 67 76-74 32 2e 63 6f 6d 82 0c   om..*.gvt2.com..
0470 - 2a 2e 75 72 63 68 69 6e-2e 63 6f 6d 82 10 2a 2e   *.urchin.com..*.
0480 - 75 72 6c 2e 67 6f 6f 67-6c 65 2e 63 6f 6d 82 16   url.google.com..
0490 - 2a 2e 79 6f 75 74 75 62-65 2d 6e 6f 63 6f 6f 6b   *.youtube-nocook
04a0 - 69 65 2e 63 6f 6d 82 0d-2a 2e 79 6f 75 74 75 62   ie.com..*.youtub
04b0 - 65 2e 63 6f 6d 82 16 2a-2e 79 6f 75 74 75 62 65   e.com..*.youtube
04c0 - 65 64 75 63 61 74 69 6f-6e 2e 63 6f 6d 82 0b 2a   education.com..*
04d0 - 2e 79 74 69 6d 67 2e 63-6f 6d 82 0b 61 6e 64 72   .ytimg.com..andr
04e0 - 6f 69 64 2e 63 6f 6d 82-04 67 2e 63 6f 82 06 67   oid.com..g.co..g
04f0 - 6f 6f 2e 67 6c 82 14 67-6f 6f 67 6c 65 2d 61 6e   oo.gl..google-an
0500 - 61 6c 79 74 69 63 73 2e-63 6f 6d 82 0a 67 6f 6f   alytics.com..goo
0510 - 67 6c 65 2e 63 6f 6d 82-12 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65 63   gle.com..googlec
0520 - 6f 6d 6d 65 72 63 65 2e-63 6f 6d 82 0a 75 72 63   ommerce.com..urc
0530 - 68 69 6e 2e 63 6f 6d 82-08 79 6f 75 74 75 2e 62   hin.com..youtu.b
0540 - 65 82 0b                                          e..
read from 0x8418770 [0x841e263] (2483 bytes => 2483 (0x9B3))
0000 - 79 6f 75 74 75 62 65 2e-63 6f 6d 82 14 79 6f 75   youtube.com..you
0010 - 74 75 62 65 65 64 75 63-61 74 69 6f 6e 2e 63 6f   tubeeducation.co

data removed due to space constraint....

05e0 - 54 13 60 9f 0b e1 b4 9c-28 2a f9 ae 02 34 6d 25   T.`.....(*...4m%
05f0 - 93 9c 82 a8 17 7b f1 85-b0 d3 0f 58 e1 fb b1 fe   .....{.....X....
0600 - 9c a1 a3 e8 fd c9 3f f4-d7 71 dc bd 8c a4 19 e0   ......?..q......
0610 - 21 23 23 55 13 8f a4 16-02 09 7e b9 af ee db 53   !##U......~....S
0620 - 64 bd 71 2f b9 39 ce 30-b7 b4 bc 54 e0 47 07 00   d.q/.9.0...T.G..
0630 - 03 81 30 82 03 7d 30 82-02 e6 a0 03 02 01 02 02   ..0..}0.........
0640 - 03 12 bb e6 30 0d 06 09-2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01   ....0...*.H.....
0650 - 05 05 00 30 4e 31 0b 30-09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02   ...0N1.0...U....
0660 - 55 53 31 10 30 0e 06 03-55 04 0a 13 07 45 71 75   US1.0...U....Equ
0670 - 69 66 61 78 31 2d 30 2b-06 03 55 04 0b 13 24 45   ifax1-0+..U...$E
0680 - 71 75 69 66 61 78 20 53-65 63 75 72 65 20 43 65   quifax Secure Ce
0690 - 72 74 69 66 69 63 61 74-65 20 41 75 74 68 6f 72   rtificate Author
06a0 - 69 74 79 30 1e 17 0d 30-32 30 35 32 31 30 34 30   ity0...020521040
06b0 - 30 30 30 5a 17 0d 31 38-30 38 32 31 30 34 30 30   000Z..1808210400
06c0 - 30 30 5a 30 42 31 0b 30-09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02   00Z0B1.0...U....
06d0 - 55 53 31 16 30 14 06 03-55 04 0a 13 0d 47 65 6f   US1.0...U....Geo
06e0 - 54 72 75 73 74 20 49 6e-63 2e 31 1b 30 19 06 03   Trust Inc.1.0...
06f0 - 55 04 03 13 12 47 65 6f-54 72 75 73 74 20 47 6c   U....GeoTrust Gl
0700 - 6f 62 61 6c 20 43 41 30-82 01 22 30 0d 06 09 2a   obal CA0.."0...*
0710 - 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 01-05 00 03 82 01 0f 00 30   .H.............0
0720 - 82 01 0a 02 82 01 01 00-da cc 18 63 30 fd f4 17   ...........c0...
0730 - 23 1a 56 7e 5b df 3c 6c-38 e4 71 b7 78 91 d4 bc   #.V~[.<l8.q.x...
0740 - a1 d8 4c f8 a8 43 b6 03-e9 4d 21 07 08 88 da 58   ..L..C...M!....X
0750 - 2f 66 39 29 bd 05 78 8b-9d 38 e8 05 b7 6a 7e 71   /f9)..x..8...j~q
0760 - a4 e6 c4 60 a6 b0 ef 80-e4 89 28 0f 9e 25 d6 ed   ...`......(..%..
0770 - 83 f3 ad a6 91 c7 98 c9-42 18 35 14 9d ad 98 46   ........B.5....F
0780 - 92 2e 4f ca f1 87 43 c1-16 95 57 2d 50 ef 89 2d   ..O...C...W-P..-
0790 - 80 7a 57 ad f2 ee 5f 6b-d2 00 8d b9 14 f8 14 15   .zW..._k........
07a0 - 35 d9 c0 46 a3 7b 72 c8-91 bf c9 55 2b cd d0 97   5..F.{r....U+...
07b0 - 3e 9c 26 64 cc df ce 83-19 71 ca 4e e6 d4 d5 7b   >.&d.....q.N...{
07c0 - a9 19 cd 55 de c8 ec d2-5e 38 53 e5 5c 4f 8c 2d   ...U....^8S.\O.-
07d0 - fe 50 23 36 fc 66 e6 cb-8e a4 39 19 00 b7 95 02   .P#6.f....9.....
07e0 - 39 91 0b 0e fe 38 2e d1-1d 05 9a f6 4d 3e 6f 0f   9....8......M>o.
07f0 - 07 1d af 2c 1e 8f 60 39-e2 fa 36 53 13 39 d4 5e   ...,..`9..6S.9.^
0800 - 26 2b db 3d a8 14 bd 32-eb 18 03 28 52 04 71 e5   &+.=...2...(R.q.
0810 - ab 33 3d e1 38 bb 07 36-84 62 9c 79 ea 16 30 f4   .3=.8..6.b.y..0.
0820 - 5f c0 2b e8 71 6b e4 f9-02 03 01 00 01 a3 81 f0   _.+.qk..........
0830 - 30 81 ed 30 1f 06 03 55-1d 23 04 18 30 16 80 14   0..0...U.#..0...
0840 - 48 e6 68 f9 2b d2 b2 95-d7 47 d8 23 20 10 4f 33   H.h.+....G.# .O3
0850 - 98 90 9f d4 30 1d 06 03-55 1d 0e 04 16 04 14 c0   ....0...U.......
0860 - 7a 98 68 8d 89 fb ab 05-64 0c 11 7d aa 7d 65 b8   z.h.....d..}.}e.
0870 - ca cc 4e 30 0f 06 03 55-1d 13 01 01 ff 04 05 30   ..N0...U.......0
0880 - 03 01 01 ff 30 0e 06 03-55 1d 0f 01 01 ff 04 04   ....0...U.......
0890 - 03 02 01 06 30 3a 06 03-55 1d 1f 04 33 30 31 30   ....0:..U...3010
08a0 - 2f a0 2d a0 2b 86 29 68-74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 63 72   /.-.+.)http://cr
08b0 - 6c 2e 67 65 6f 74 72 75-73 74 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 63   l.geotrust.com/c
08c0 - 72 6c 73 2f 73 65 63 75-72 65 63 61 2e 63 72 6c   rls/secureca.crl
08d0 - 30 4e 06 03 55 1d 20 04-47 30 45 30 43 06 04 55   0N..U. .G0E0C..U
08e0 - 1d 20 00 30 3b 30 39 06-08 2b 06 01 05 05 07 02   . .0;09..+......
08f0 - 01 16 2d 68 74 74 70 73-3a 2f 2f 77 77 77 2e 67   ..-https://www.g
0900 - 65 6f 74 72 75 73 74 2e-63 6f 6d 2f 72 65 73 6f   eotrust.com/reso
0910 - 75 72 63 65 73 2f 72 65-70 6f 73 69 74 6f 72 79   urces/repository
0920 - 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86-f7 0d 01 01 05 05 00 03   0...*.H.........
0930 - 81 81 00 76 e1 12 6e 4e-4b 16 12 86 30 06 b2 81   ...v..nNK...0...
0940 - 08 cf f0 08 c7 c7 71 7e-66 ee c2 ed d4 3b 1f ff   ......q~f....;..
0950 - f0 f0 c8 4e d6 43 38 b0-b9 30 7d 18 d0 55 83 a2   ...N.C8..0}..U..
0960 - 6a cb 36 11 9c e8 48 66-a3 6d 7f b8 13 d4 47 fe   j.6...Hf.m....G.
0970 - 8b 5a 5c 73 fc ae d9 1b-32 19 38 ab 97 34 14 aa   .Z\s....2.8..4..
0980 - 96 d2 eb a3 1c 14 08 49-b6 bb e5 91 ef 83 36 eb   .......I......6.
0990 - 1d 56 6f ca da bc 73 63-90 e4 7f 7b 3e 22 cb 3d   .Vo...sc...{>".=
09a0 - 07 ed 5f 38 74 9c e3 03-50 4e a1 af 98 ee 61 f2   .._8t...PN....a.
09b0 - 84 3f 12                                          .?.
read from 0x8418770 [0x841dd1b] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 16 03 02 01 4b                                    ....K
read from 0x8418770 [0x841dd20] (331 bytes => 331 (0x14B))
0000 - 0c 00 01 47 03 00 17 41-04 6d 9f 05 f0 4a 33 fb   ...G...A.m...J3.
0010 - cd df 1f fa 77 ee df 37-27 7b 90 72 91 b9 db be   ....w..7'{.r....
0020 - 1c 2a 2a 18 3b 7c bd 89-83 30 6a 94 3d b2 39 0f   .**.;|...0j.=.9.
0030 - 6e 0c 8b 7d cb ce af 60-5a c7 a7 75 87 51 05 bb   n..}...`Z..u.Q..
0040 - 12 bd b0 2f 76 1d 66 87-46 01 00 79 d3 43 0b 73   .../v.f.F..y.C.s
0050 - 02 13 35 7b ac fd 10 52-78 31 43 c8 18 27 13 52   ..5{...Rx1C..'.R
0060 - d9 26 e2 ac 0f 5f 0f 93-9c d4 60 ca 52 1f 0b 96   .&..._....`.R...
0070 - 30 89 5f dc 72 c9 8e 93-06 5e d0 a5 3b dd ab a2   0._.r....^..;...
0080 - 0f 5f 9a bb 75 f9 62 7f-d2 4d f0 fd e1 06 f5 d4   ._..u.b..M......
0090 - b9 e3 af 2a 7e 66 13 6c-bf e7 34 41 78 a8 e5 52   ...*~f.l..4Ax..R
00a0 - de 74 1a 01 d8 30 9c da-2e e7 67 16 80 49 e3 71   .t...0....g..I.q
00b0 - d7 c4 db a1 c9 be 28 41-92 10 47 0f df e4 21 58   ......(A..G...!X
00c0 - 21 84 78 4c 43 54 68 70-a1 2b 50 ed 40 5e 03 7b   !.xLCThp.+P.@^.{
00d0 - 1b 75 75 46 84 c2 b5 38-39 68 90 94 74 e2 6f ce   .uuF...89h..t.o.
00e0 - 0a 58 b7 d8 db 2d 12 e2-e8 4b 0c ea ed 31 ce 63   .X...-...K...1.c
00f0 - b2 99 ca 86 4b a1 ab db-cc 59 17 99 33 19 f1 0a   ....K....Y..3...
0100 - 64 a9 61 f4 6a eb f0 a2-32 73 02 5e d7 75 23 6b   d.a.j...2s.^.u#k
0110 - a0 2c d7 d2 51 5d c6 c2-b6 04 89 60 5b 2a 0b 45   .,..Q].....`[*.E
0120 - 7e 48 c3 34 fb c1 cd dc-d3 56 f7 cb 29 5f 52 60   ~H.4.....V..)_R`
0130 - 82 c9 10 53 a0 5e 48 67-2d c4 75 48 d8 01 f4 68   ...S.^Hg-.uH...h
0140 - a7 01 b1 02 e6 7c c7 d9-b1 a8 b9                  .....|.....
read from 0x8418770 [0x841dd1b] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 16 03 02 00 04                                    .....
read from 0x8418770 [0x841dd20] (4 bytes => 4 (0x4))
0000 - 0e                                                .
0004 - <SPACES/NULS>
write to 0x8418770 [0x8427978] (75 bytes => 75 (0x4B))
0000 - 16 03 02 00 46 10 00 00-42 41 04 bc d0 67 04 df   ....F...BA...g..
0010 - 43 dd 63 cb 30 57 d4 71-5a 72 10 ac 05 c7 7a ef   C.c.0W.qZr....z.
0020 - 39 17 48 96 68 2f b7 c7-b0 80 93 96 c8 38 f0 64   9.H.h/.......8.d
0030 - 4a bb e9 01 23 a9 78 22-02 ff 2a cb 23 51 5d e4   J...#.x"..*.#Q].
0040 - b8 f3 74 54 2f e5 cd 17-ae fb 9e                  ..tT/......
write to 0x8418770 [0x8427978] (6 bytes => 6 (0x6))
0000 - 14 03 02 00 01 01                                 ......
write to 0x8418770 [0x8427978] (69 bytes => 69 (0x45))
0000 - 16 03 02 00 40 45 af 8e-42 af 3b 85 9b ee 70 fb   ....@E..B.;...p.
0010 - 9b 55 aa d4 99 bf 0f 94-94 fc 08 aa 90 b2 14 83   .U..............
0020 - cd c4 f1 44 15 f9 1c 8e-57 ad 68 36 6e a3 73 f0   ...D....W.h6n.s.
0030 - 79 ae 0d 0b 34 09 8d e8-ba 81 0c d6 ee 99 d4 c5   y...4...........
0040 - 22 6b 5f dd e5                                    "k_..
read from 0x8418770 [0x841dd1b] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 16 03 02 00 ae                                    .....
read from 0x8418770 [0x841dd20] (174 bytes => 174 (0xAE))
0000 - 04 00 00 aa 00 01 89 c0-00 a4 de 0f 0f 57 87 f9   .............W..
0010 - cb 7c 87 b3 c9 f8 39 1f-c5 e8 5d 19 60 77 c9 3e   .|....9...].`w.>
0020 - 25 54 c0 e4 e8 1b 67 9b-3c 12 f0 23 79 4d 85 4c   %T....g.<..#yM.L
0030 - bd 90 50 7a e3 2b 15 93-17 49 69 69 58 f1 71 bb   ..Pz.+...IiiX.q.
0040 - f7 26 c4 06 f6 1c 16 7a-b4 e7 dc b0 2c 27 01 a5   .&.....z....,'..
0050 - 8d 24 e4 42 c2 bc b9 e0-13 76 51 b1 6a 71 e1 b9   .$.B.....vQ.jq..
0060 - ce d7 23 4b 70 21 68 40-14 c7 33 75 e7 b7 4a 38   ..#Kp!h@..3u..J8
0070 - d9 e6 ce f4 6e 88 38 d0-6e f2 55 61 d4 ed 3b fa   ....n.8.n.Ua..;.
0080 - a4 03 05 86 5a 49 a0 ff-e9 bc 5d ac 5a c5 f6 de   ....ZI....].Z...
0090 - 46 c6 08 4d cc fa 1e e8-bf ba 86 9c 3d 49 2e 9f   F..M........=I..
00a0 - 13 85 ba 7a e4 35 5b 51-f5 eb 1b 7a c3 76         ...z.5[Q...z.v
read from 0x8418770 [0x841dd1b] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 14 03 02 00 01                                    .....
read from 0x8418770 [0x841dd20] (1 bytes => 1 (0x1))
0000 - 01                                                .
read from 0x8418770 [0x841dd1b] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 16 03 02 00 40                                    ....@
read from 0x8418770 [0x841dd20] (64 bytes => 64 (0x40))
0000 - 90 23 01 ea 7e 92 31 15-ee 27 4c cb 10 42 3d 41   .#..~.1..'L..B=A
0010 - 93 92 29 56 be b4 d2 a7-65 e4 6b 00 9b 13 07 c9   ..)V....e.k.....
0020 - 49 4a 82 6f 66 17 4e 98-b0 5b 5c 88 99 10 9e 39   IJ.of.N..[\....9
0030 - 72 23 01 f6 2b 37 c7 0c-00 3c 38 f0 3f ff 70 48   r#..+7...<8.?.pH
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.google.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 4500 bytes and written 375 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.1
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: 30802DE6B553B57DE17D097039FAF41ED8957043E0B6230739B75D4184E530D6
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: DAF21C9FB81B29B1E7C23920B7FBC9ADCC7DE76AE4872A9D88DE9BB79E425305102FB29A248BA2DFDD149591955E0A47
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 100800 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - de 0f 0f 57 87 f9 cb 7c-87 b3 c9 f8 39 1f c5 e8   ...W...|....9...
    0010 - 5d 19 60 77 c9 3e 25 54-c0 e4 e8 1b 67 9b 3c 12   ].`w.>%T....g.<.
    0020 - f0 23 79 4d 85 4c bd 90-50 7a e3 2b 15 93 17 49   .#yM.L..Pz.+...I
    0030 - 69 69 58 f1 71 bb f7 26-c4 06 f6 1c 16 7a b4 e7   iiX.q..&.....z..
    0040 - dc b0 2c 27 01 a5 8d 24-e4 42 c2 bc b9 e0 13 76   ..,'...$.B.....v
    0050 - 51 b1 6a 71 e1 b9 ce d7-23 4b 70 21 68 40 14 c7   Q.jq....#Kp!h@..
    0060 - 33 75 e7 b7 4a 38 d9 e6-ce f4 6e 88 38 d0 6e f2   3u..J8....n.8.n.
    0070 - 55 61 d4 ed 3b fa a4 03-05 86 5a 49 a0 ff e9 bc   Ua..;.....ZI....
    0080 - 5d ac 5a c5 f6 de 46 c6-08 4d cc fa 1e e8 bf ba   ].Z...F..M......
    0090 - 86 9c 3d 49 2e 9f 13 85-ba 7a e4 35 5b 51 f5 eb   ..=I.....z.5[Q..
    00a0 - 1b 7a c3 76                                       .z.v

    Start Time: 1412264657
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This certification path exception was indeed caused by a missing intermediate certificate on the load balancer of the site.  After installing the missing certificate on the LB, I continued to see this exception.  Finally, I realized that debugging with "Fiddler" had bit me.  The Android system was complaining about the Fiddler certificate rather than the site certificate.  After installing the Fiddler certificate on to the Android, the exception went away and I can now see all the Https traffic between the Android and the server.